# PyCharm 2018.3 on ubuntu 18. def__init__(self,x,y): ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

When tried to execute below piece of python code in PyCharm 2018.3 on ubuntu 18.04 everything updated & upgrated in Lenovo ideapad 110

```
class Snow():
    def__init__(self,x,y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.speed = random.randint (1, 3)
       self.img.num = random.randint (1, 4)
       self.image.filename = "snow" + str(self.img_num)+ "png"
       self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (SNOW_SIZE, SNOW_SIZE))
```

I face error as below

> def__init__(self,x,y):
>
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any suggestions as to why I am facing such issue?

Comment: There is a space missing between def and _